# Risk calculation probability

Tags: statistics

I have a probability of a breach happening for Company A in 2019: .25
I have a probability of a breach happening for Company A historically (2010-2019): 0.10

How can I integrate a model where both probabilities are communicated?

Comment: Were your 2 probabilities derived from 2 different methods?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  Since there is a 25% chance in 2019, there must be at least a 25% change in years 2010 through 2019 (inclusive).